# Is there a way to split a line plot into branches, with the branches forking off the main line in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set as follows:

```
data <- data.frame( 
ID = c(rep(1:4, each = 16)),
time = c(rep(1:4, each = 4, times = 4)),
drug1 = c(rep(1:2, each = 2, times = 16)),
drug2 = rep(c(1,2,2,3), times = 16),
value = c(sample(1:100, 64, replace = FALSE)))
```

In this study ID took drug1 (1 or 2) for time points 1 and 2, then for time 3 and 4, ID may have stayed on the same drug (1 or 2), or had a switch (1-->2, or 2-->3)

I have two issues.

1. I would like to make a line plot, plotting the means for the drug condition where for time 1 and 2 the grouping in ggplot follows variable "drug" but for time 3 and 4 it follows "drug 2".

An example might be something like (https://ibb.co/6gLP0Hv)

2. I also want to ignore any NA that are in the drug2 column if it's week 3 and 4, but keep the data in for week 1 and 2.

I have used filter from an answer below and it was close, but not quite what I visualized what look right.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced a line plot is the best way to go as you have multiple measures per drug/time so it will look odd/misleading... perhaps a jitter/scatterplot is better (just change to geom_line if you want - **the bit you are after here really is the `filter`**):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(data %>% filter(time == 1| time == 2), 
    mapping = aes(x = time, y = mean, shape = drug), width = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(data %>% filter(time == 3| time == 4), 
    mapping = aes(x = time, y = mean, shape = drug2), width = 0.1, color = 'red')
```

Comment: You're right, filter is what I was looking for- and I see what you mean about line being the incorrect plot. I'm going to rephrase my question and change my reproducible example to try and illustrate my issue better. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have edited my original question. I gave an image for the graph I would like to make.